# Test hypothesis for one median, std or percentile using boostrap

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean, bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for testing the mean by creating samples centered around H0

```
Private Sub Boostrap()
    Dim datanew() As Double
    N = UBound(Victor1)
    ReDim Preserve datanew(N) As Double
  
        For I = 1 To UBound(Victor1)
            datanew(I) = Victor1(I) - xlApp.Average(Victor1) + Val(H0.Text)
        Next I      

    ' Perform bootstrap mean testing
    BootstrapMeanTesting datanew, Val(Iterations), Val(H0.Text)
End Sub
```

I want to perform the test for the median, std, and percentile. How do I create the Bootstrap distribution under H0?